# Gstreamer Compilation - No such element or plugin 'fakesrc'

Tags: c, gstreamer

I have compiled gstreamer 1.9.x according to the 
[README](https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/master/README)

section COMPILING FROM SOURCE TARBALLS.

There was no error in compilation but once after compilation, to test whether compilation is successful(According to README), I have run the command `"tools/gst-launch-1.0 -v fakesrc num_buffers=5 ! fakesink"`
 but I am getting error "`No such element or plugin 'fakesrc'`".

I even tried gst-inspect-1.0 to check how many plugin installed, It is only showing two plugins(bin,pipeline).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got fixed after running this command

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Hope it may help someone.